# Web Service returning limited no of records

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am using Web Service in my Asp.Net web application.Output of my web service is truncated one.I am not getting full output as expected.

Does anybody know how to increase return type length limit??I am sending long parameter list as input.
Is there any upper limit parameter length??